# Ribbon button as menu

Tags: button, drop-down-menu, ribbon

How should Ribbon XML look like to create a button like button "New" (with a small arrow below text) when you click it to create a list with 2 new small buttons like a list?

Button image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a RibbonSplitButton -- see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonsplitbutton.aspx).